# VBA list of errors in IDE

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, syntax-error, vbe

I'm working with the VBA IDE provided with Access, and although when there's an error the offending line of code turns red, I can't for the life of me find a way to view the error.

[image]

Note that my question is **not** how to fix this error, but simply how to **view** the error that is making this code red.

There is no option to show the error window, and I'm at a loss. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: Debug >> Compile. A MsgBox should appear telling you what's wrong.

Comment: Is that the exact syntax? I'm not familiar with it

Comment: What do you mean by "Is that the exact syntax"? What is "that" in reference to?

Comment: `Debug >> Compile` - I've never seen it before, and am not sure how to use it. `A MsgBox should appear` - how?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h8UU.png

Comment: If you always want to immediately see the error msg, you can turn on [this option](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/2/13/turn-off-annoying-error-alerts-in-visual-basic-editor-vbe). But it's very annoying, so most programmers have turned it off. Using "Compile" when you need it is much better.

Comment: Also note that you will only get "Syntax error" with this line. Not really more information than the red color. :)